# The anapole moment, derivation from Dirac current density

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, electric-current, dirac-equation, multipole-expansion

Basically I am looking for a way to expand the electromagnetic interaction energy $W = A_{\mu}j^{\mu}$ (both $A$ and $j$ obtained from the Dirac equation) similar to the classical expansion in multipole moments, having in mind that there will be a term in the expansion called the anapole moment which is the only moment by which dark matter interacts with electromagnetic fields.

Up to now, I have not found any derivation and I'd like to know how this works or if at least my approach to this problem (see below, boldface letters) is correct.

In an experimental-physicist's paper I have found that the anapole moment is given by $$\bar{\chi} \gamma^{\mu}\gamma_5 \chi \partial_{\nu} F^{\mu \nu}$$ and actually is derived from the toroidal moment

$$\bar{\chi}_2 \gamma^{\mu}\gamma_5 \chi_1\partial_{\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$ which is a current in a ring folded to a torus. In the limes $\chi_2 \rightarrow \chi_1$ the torus is "contracted to a point" so one gets an "anapole".

I know that the interaction energy is given by $A_{\mu}j^{\mu}$ and that the current can be expressed via the electromagnetic field strength tensor $j_{\mu} = \partial_{\nu}F^{\mu \nu}$, which lead me to the *assumption* that the potential $A_\mu$ has to be expanded so that, in the end, one obtains the following anapole term of this expansion:

$$A_{\mu,anapole} = \bar{\chi}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_5\chi$$

Something that bothers me is that the Dirac current density is given by $$j^{\mu} = \Psi \gamma^{\mu} \Psi$$ so the interaction energy should, in theory, be given by $$j^{\mu}A_{\mu} = -e\Psi \gamma^{\mu} \Psi A_{\mu}$$ which ultimately confuses me, as I can't think of a way to retrieve the anapole moment from this interaction energy.

**Further rough ideas of mine, how this could work:** $$\Gamma^A_{\mu}=\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_5$$ is a bilinear covariant, one of the 16 matrices that define the Clifford-Dirac algebra. They are linear independent and form a basis. I know that they behave like a scalar/pseudoscalar/vector/pseudovector/rank 2 tensor under Lorentz transformation, PLUS they are all trace-free tensors. The classical multipole moments are also trace-free tensors, which led me to the assumption that one might maybe expand in these matrices? But even if, I have no idea how to find an ansatz to the expansion. Maybe one in the end obtains something like
$$\bar{\Psi}\Gamma_1\Psi + \bar{\Psi}\Gamma_2\Psi + ...$$ for the multipole moments. I also cannot find any information on what the bilinear covariants are actually used for in particle physics.

Comment: haven't heard about anapole moment before.. is this some kind of composite moment from several multipoles?

Comment: No, there is actually a whole family of $2^l$ toroid moments that is usually omitted. As far as I know the anapole moment is a toroid vector moment contracted to a point. 

In general, if you expand the current density formally you will not only receive $2^l$-pole moments but also quantities like so-called *mean-square radii* (which describe the spatial extent of each $2^l$-pole) and toroid moments, without both of which a multipole parametrization is incomplete.

Comment: interesting, I found the wikipedia page about toroidal moments.. but is that exhaustive? I mean, couldn't there be any other 'missing moments' in a given field description?

Comment: This is in the classical case, though!

Comment: I have not understood the topic fully, so I can't tell you for sure! The way these additional moments were found is by tensor decomposition (see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112024/toroid-moments-tensor-decomposition for details) so that all moments are trace-free symmetric tensors. In the current expansion, though, many moments can be expressed through the charge multipole moments and radii (remember $\dot{\rho} + \text{div }\mathbf{j} =0$!) which reduces the number of moments that are actually "generated" by the current.

Comment: Can you post links to the papers you're reading? My understanding is that anapole dark matter is a pretty new idea (firmly in the territory of "not forbidden yet"); most of the literature for the past 15+ years is attempts to related the [measured nonzero anapole moment in cesium](https://www.sciencemag.org/content/275/5307/1759) to other parity-violating observables among nucleons and nuclei, which is a messier problem.

Comment: It's mainly http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0503